# Xamarin archiving process stuck in "Packaging" step?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 and trying to archive my app for the first time (to publish).

The archiving process begins, and completes several steps, but then seems to be stuck endlessly in the in 'Packaging MyAppName" step. It's now been about 4 hours, and no change.  It's still stuck.  The progress bar animation is still going, and Visual Studio is still fully responsive.

I suspect that maybe I have too many pictures because I have about 12, each of which has a copy in the xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, and ldpi folders.  But again, it's just a guess.  The app worked fine in testing.  In windows explorer, the file containing all my project files is 284 MB.

I can't seem to get any message log about what's happening.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is also in this video. Do not forget to package by Release. There is probably no interest in the pictures of the problem you are taking with.

Xamarin Android Release Build APK NOV 2016 :

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2umj5ihqQDs&t=283s)